# How is the d[A] interacting with the integral in the problem?

Tags: integration

I am pulling from a Chemistry book, attempting to understand this derivation and I'm a tad rusty with integration. Need a quick hand, please.

Given the equation: 
$$2N_2O_5(g) \rightarrow 4NO_2(g) + 0_2(g)$$

they give the following rate law: 
$$Rate=-\frac{\Delta[N_2O_5]}{\Delta t}=k[N_2O_5] $$

from which they use Calculus to derive:

$$ln\frac{[N_2O_5]_t}{[N_2O_5]_0}=-kt$$

For which they give the general derivation, substituting $[A]$ for $[N_2O_5]$ into the non-integrated rate law.

$$\frac{-d[A]}{dt}=k[A]$$

Rearranging to give:

$$\frac{-d[A]}{[A]}=kdt$$

Integrating from $time=0$ to $time=t$,

$$-\int_{[A]_0}^{[A]_t} \frac{d[A]}{[A]} = k \int_{0}^{t} dt$$

to give:

$$ -\lbrace \ln{[A]_t} - \ln{[A]_0} \rbrace = k(t-0)$$

which you rearrange to get the integrated rate law.

So I remember that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)=F(b) - F(a)$ and that $\int \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln(x)$. I also recall $\int dx = x$. Where I am held up is that I recall $\int \frac{a}{b} = \int a + \int \frac{1}{b}$. So what is to be said of $\int d[A]$? Does it evaluate to one? In general, what is this?

Comment: *evaluate to zero

Comment: I think your problem understanding might come from the funky notation. If we wrote $u=[A]$, and remembered $\int \frac{du}{u}$ is the same as $\int \frac{1}{u} du$, would that help?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int \frac ab \neq \int a + \int \frac 1b$. I think you may be confusing this with [integration-by-parts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).

As you said $\int dx = x$ (+ constant). So $\int d[A]$ is simply $[A]$ + constant . In your problem, the constant is ignored because the integral is **definite**, that is with bounds.

Comment: Thank you! I see what y'all are getting at. The integral is with respect to $d{A}$. As to my misconception on integration-by-parts, thanks for pointing that out. I'll make sure to focus on that during my review.